# Magento: Get Website ID from Website Name

Tags: php, magento

As the title says. I don't want the ID of the current website, I want the ID of any website by supplying only that websites name.

I have this code:

```
$siteModel = Mage::getResourceModel( 'core/website_collection' )->addFieldToFilter( 'name', $site )->getFirstItem();
$siteId = $siteModel->getId();
```

But `$siteId` ends up empty.

If all I have is the name of a website, how do I get its IDs?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your code is working for me. However I would recommend you to use the website "code" instead of the website "name" if you can. Are you sure the name you provide is right?

Comment: @adrien54 the name I am providing is `base`. When I output the SQL from the $siteModel collection (using `->__toString()`) I get the following: `SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_website` AS `main_table` WHERE (name = 'base')` - but all I get back is an empty string?

Comment: Can you show the rows you have in the table core_website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need debug the collection by `->getSelect()->__toString()`

for checking it give right value or not.

```
    $siteModelCollection = Mage::getResourceModel( 'core/website_collection' )->addFieldToFilter( 'name', $site );
// print the Query
    echo $Query = $siteModelCollection ->getSelect()->__toString();
    echo $siteId =$siteModelCollection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

### Update:

**Use load():**

for this case you need to  call `load()` function of `resource model` of `core/website` for getting proper collection

Now you can get id of first store by using below code:

```
$siteModelCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->load()->addFieldToFilter( 'name', $site);
echo $Query = $siteModelCollection ->getSelect()->__toString();
echo $siteId =$siteModelCollection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `addFieldToFilter` method incorrectly.
Try this approach:

```
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('eq', $siteName))
    ->getFirstItem();
$websiteId = $website->getId();
```